# What are the best way to load incremental data into Database using Spark?

Tags: database, postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, upsert

I have tried multiple ways to incremental load (`upsert`) into the `Postgress` Database (RDS) using `Spark` (with `Glue Job`) but did not find satisfactory performance.

I have tried the below ways:

**1. Delete the records based on the primary Key and append new records**

> In this approach, I `delete` the records where the `primary key` exists in
> incremental data. This is done by Python API such as `pg8000` etc. Once it gets successfully completed, I write data using `Spark` in `append` mode.
>
> This approach works very smooth when the incremental load is less but
> with high volumes, Delete and writing takes time.

**2. Writing data into a staging table and triggering DB store procedure**

> I have also tried this alternative way to handle the `upsert` with a `relational database`. Here I am writing data into a Staging table using `Spark` and triggering `Store Procedure` (with `pg8000`). The Store Procedure will `upsert` the data from the staging table to the final table.
>
> With the approach, we have to manage multiple `Store procedure` and also have to depend on the `Database` (in case we are not owning that system). Handling the staging to final upsert will be tricky if the previous job gets failed after writing data into staging and before triggering the Store procedure. Overall I feel this approach needs good orchestration not only with the Spark but with Store procedure as well.

***Is there any way that can handle upsert in a relational database (Postgres/MySQL/Oracle etc) very smoothly and efficiently using Spark?***